# Make MRTG graph Titles more Specific?

Tags: network-monitoring, traffic-management, mrtg

MRTG defaults to titling each traffic graph as "Traffic Analysis for ${port_int}"  I would like to instead have each graph titled by the description of the switchport.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely possible. The text on and around the graphs is fully themeable. The documentation shows this pretty well. For example, to change the "Traffic Analysis for xyz" text use the key:

```
Title[GigE2/1]: Description of switch port GigE2/1
```

If you're generating your MRTG graphs by way of cfgmaker

```
cfgmaker --ifdesc=descr $OtherOptions
```

Should render you the same thing automatically. Your titles won't be `Traffic analysis for 2/1` they will be `Traffic analysis for Payments Server`, which sounds like what you're looking for. If you need something more then that, then you need to start looking into the "--if-template" function of cfgmaker. It allows a much more detailed customization of the text fields, but does require some scripting.

Comment: could you link the doc?  I ran cfgmaker with the --ifdesc=desc option and it threw an error stating that 'desc' was no a valid value for ifdesc

Comment: http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/index.en.html is the doc-home, with cfgmaker at http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/cfgmaker.en.html and it should be `descr` not `desc`. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.cfg` file for the device, look for the `Title[]:` definitions and modify those to your heart's delight. See http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-reference.en.html#Title_CONTENT.